# Using custom icon markers with Folium?

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

Given that Folium builds on the Leaflet JS library, I was wondering if it could provide the same functionality as Leaflet for custom icon markers.

Scanning through the tutorial [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium), I'm somewhat doubtful that this is possible, but I thought I would ask here to confirm. It looks as if the marker icons are limited to those provided on [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/).

```
map_1 = folium.Map(location=[45.372, -121.6972], zoom_start=12,tiles='Stamen Terrain')
map_1.simple_marker([45.3300, -121.6823], popup='Some Other Location',marker_color='red',marker_icon='info-sign')
map_1.create_map(path='iconTest.html')
```

If this is not supported, is anyone familiar with another Python mapping framework that would support the use of markers with custom icons?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the functionality didn't exist. I made a request to the contributors of the Folium library on Github, and they promptly delivered!

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/228

https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/230